# How to Remove No Data from a NetCDF Raster Layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, zonal-statistics, nodata

**Question:** How to remove no data from a NetCDF Raster Layer?

I am trying to use the Zonal Statistics as Table tool in ArcGIS to calculate the mean. The problem  is I am not getting the correct mean, because I have no data information inside the Raster Layer. I am able to not view the no data and change the value in symbology in properties, but still I get the incorrect mean.  I have also tried going into ArcCatalog and changing the no data, but it does not work for NetCDF Raster Layers, just Raster.

Comment: Can you convert the netCDF file in any way?

Comment: It is converted to a Raster Layer.

Comment: Did you try setting the `statistics_ignore_value` in the RasterStatistics Environment before executing the tool? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/raster-statistics.htm